# Java handling null Strings with error log

Tags: java

I want to initialize a String variable and later assign a value to it using

```
if (){} else if(){}
```

This is what I have done:

```
    String roleName;

    // A and B are string constants
    if (userRoleslist.contains(A)) {
           roleName = A;
    } else if (userRoleslist.contains(B)) {
                roleName = B;
    }
    if (!roleName.equals(null)) {
           audit.info("User: " + userName + " successfully authorized as " +
                        roleName + " to perform JMX operations.");

           return roleName;
     } else {
           String msg = "User: " + userName + " not authorized to perform JMX operations.";
           log.error(msg);
           throw new NullPointerException();
     }
```

The problem is that the error is not logged to the console. Only the NullPointerException is thrown and point the line if

```
(!roleName.equals(null)) {
```

Also, additionally  can I leave out the NullPointerException and  a log.error only?

Comment: null != roleName instead of rolename.equals(null), because you can not call null.equals

Comment: Info goes to `audit`, error goes to `log` in your code. Sure you have two different loggers?

Comment: @Jens: Well, `roleName != null`. The "null first in conditions" is pretty outdated, pointless in Java and widely regarded as less readable.

Comment: `roleName.equals(null)` can *never* return true. Well... not if implemented correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if (!roleName.equals(null)) {
```

must be

```
if (roleName != null) {
```

When you do a null check you should do like this.
As roleName is null, calling a method on it will give you a null pointer exception.

Answer (score 2):

roleName.equals(null) will give you nullpointer exception instead use roleName!=null .